# Which package is better among WPAPI and wordpress-rest-api on NPM

Tags: wordpress, npm, wordpress-rest-api, npmjs

Links to both the packages are here

[Wordpress-rest-api](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wordpress-rest-api)

[WPAPI](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wpapi)

Which of these packages is better to use and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm the author of both, so I can help clarify this: they're actually different versions of the same package!

`wordpress-rest-api` is the older version, we renamed it to `wpapi` for consistency and brevity prior to our 1.0 release. If you install `wordpress-rest-api` you should get a deprecation notice instructing you to use `wpapi` instead.

`wpapi` will be used going forward for all future releases.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!